# su (sudo) command not found Galaxy S Vibrant

Tags: rooting, samsung-vibrant, z4root

I was wondering if any of you has seen this behavior:

I have an unrooted *Galaxy S Vibrant* and I was trying to root it permanently with z4root, unsuccessfully. While I try to do it permantly it seems to do it, but when I try to run *Titanium Backup* or any app that requires root permissions, it won't gain privileges. So, I installed a terminal app, and when I tried to run the `su` command it displays a `command not found` error.

My question is, what is missing from the OS? Any Idea? I know that you must have to be root in order to run certains commands but in that case it should display another error message?

Comment: It would seem that your Vibrant is not rooted; you said "I try to doi permantly it seems to do it" -- what exactly does it do?  If it's any help, I rooted my Vibrant by flashing the SuperUser package straight up.  You can also flash a kernel that roots.  Much better than z4root IMO.

Comment: It stays on the blue window with the 'adquiring root blah bla' message... If you can point how to do that flash I'll sure give it a try... Thanks

Comment: Download [this](http://downloads.androidsu.com/superuser/Superuser-3.0.7-efghi-signed.zip) to the root of your SD card, name it update.zip, reboot into recovery and flash it ("Install packages" or similar).

Comment: @MatthewRead I did what you pointed me and it gives me the message **E:failed to verify whole-file signature Installation aborted**... Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Oh, you might have ["3E recovery"](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/13022/1465).  You'd need to Odin to something with 2E recovery.  If you're stock 2.2 then you'll probably want [Eugene's JK2 Froyo](http://www.google.com/search?q=Eugene_2E_JK2_Froyo.zip) (not sure where to get it reliably anymore) which just has 2E recovery and minor tweaks from stock.  If you want to move to something else after that I recommend Bionix Nextgen V1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SU binaries are not included with the original distribution of Android, because they are not used at all by any stock system functions. Obviously, there are those of us that like to be able to do those things ;) Most rooting processes take care of this, but some leave it out. Hence the [file](http://downloads.androidsu.com/superuser/Superuser-3.0.7-efghi-signed.zip) @Matthew Read linked to should take care of your problem, if you follow the process he outlined :)

If you'd like to read more about it, you can visit the [Superuser](http://androidsu.com/superuser/) website and find more downloads there, although the link posted supports Eclair, Froyo, Gingerbread, Honeycomb and Ice Cream Sandwich. So it should cover you :)